# how to add variables together in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I want to use a variable which is composed of another vsts variable and text, for instance:

```
vnetname = $vnet_prefix + "vnetid"
```

However i get an error saying that "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument `+`.

Anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean use the variable in build/release processes, then you can add a variable like this (reference below screenshot):

```
 vnetname = $(vnet_prefix)_vnetid
```

Then you can use the variable `$vnetname` or `$(vnetname)` directly, see [Build variables-Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) for how to use the variables in different tools.

---

Alternatively you can pass the value with [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

1. Copy and paste below strings then save as ***.ps1** file:

   ```
   $value = $env:vnet_prefix + "vnetid"

   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=vnetname]$value"
   ```
2. Check in the PS file
3. Add a PowerShell task to run the PS file
4. Use the variable **$vnetname** in later steps

[image]

Comment: @itye1970 Have you resolved the issue? any update? If that works for your, please Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.